# msbuild fails and returns 1 when when I assign stdout and stdout to os.devnull, returns 0 otherwise

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, msbuild

I am trying to write a python script that checks out a revision from a mercurial repo for a visual studio 2010 native c++ project, builds it, and then runs a program under various scenarios.  Then I will compare results from other builds, etc.  So I am just getting started with a prototype, and I have:

```
from subprocess import call
import os
import tempfile
import sys


def main():

    temp_repo_name = 'temprepo'
    d = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    os.chdir(os.path.normpath(d))

    command1 = ['hg', 'clone', r'C:\temp\1\jxg_hcr', temp_repo_name]

    devnull = open(os.devnull,'w')

    rc1 = call(command1,stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)

    if rc1 != 0:
        print('could not clone repo into temporary directory.  Terminating Program')
        sys.exit(1)

    devnull.close()

    devnull = open(os.devnull,'w')

    os.chdir(temp_repo_name)

    command2 = [r'msbuild', r'hcr_dll.sln', r'/t:Rebuild',r'/p:Configuration=Release']
    rc2 = call(command2,stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)

    print rc2
    if rc2 != 0:
        print('could not build repo.  Terminating Program')
        sys.exit(1)

    devnull.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run this, I get the following output on my console:

```
C:\programming\eclipse_workspace\hcr_cli_build>python hcr_cli_build.py
0
1
could not build repo.  Terminating Program
```

But when I change the line for command2 to

```
rc2 = call(command2)
```

I get

```
0
<bunch of build output>
0
```

and it builds successfully.  I do not know why it would fail when I redirect.

Any Ideas?  Maybe just a silly error I cannot see?

NOTE: I don't think I really need to close and re-open devnull each time, but it was just something I was trying out when I was trying to figure out the issue.  I get the same results when I just keep it open the whole time and close it at the very end.

EDIT1:  This also fails from the command line when I tried it per the suggestion of David Hess.

EDIT2:  I have also verified this same issue occurs when I create an empty C# console application with the boiler plate Main function.  It will build via the gui and on the command line when msbuild is not redirected to NUL, but when I do redirect, it returns 1 and does not build.

Bounty Edit: I am most interested in why this is happening.  Obviously, I would also like to be able to succeed silently and just output a message saying "Build went okay" if the return code was 0, so if nobody can tell me why it is happening, the bounty will go to the best solution.

I also tried a bash script on mintty.exe:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1 2 3 4
 do
  echo "doing $i"
  msbuild.exe /c/temp/$i/jxg_hcr/hcr_dll.sln //t:Rebuild //p:Configuration=Release
  echo $?
 done
```

works (it prints all the output and builds successfully and then prints 0 to the console), but

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1 2 3 4
 do
  echo "doing $i"
  msbuild.exe /c/temp/$i/jxg_hcr/hcr_dll.sln //t:Rebuild //p:Configuration=Release > /dev/null
  echo $?
 done
```

does not perform the build and just returns 1 to the console.

Comment: Does it work from a command shell? I.e. `msbuild ... >NUL 2>&1`

Comment: @DavidK.Hess - good idea.  It also fails from the command shell.  Guess it has nothing to do with python.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in msbuild: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/633122/msbuild-fails-with-1-when-redirecting-the-output-1-nul-2-anywhere

Comment: @aganders3 - ahhhhh how did you find that?  i must be stupid.  i thought i searched as best as i could.  oh well.  maybe waste of a bounty here......

Comment: @oob Nah, you're not stupid. In my experience we just overlook things sometimes when we spend too much time on a problem. That's what sites like this are for - fresh eyeballs.

Comment: @aganders3 - you should answer the question so you can get the bounty.  since this is a bug, and I asked why it doesn't work, your answer fulfills the requirements.  otherwise the bounty points are just going to go to waste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in msbuild:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/633122/msbuild-fails-with-1-when-redirecting-the-output-1-nul-2-anywhere

Comment: @oob I didn't know the bounty would go to waste - I figured you got to keep the points if nobody answered.

Comment: yeah that is how it works.  i'm accepting this answer so that if a better one doesn't come along, the bounty will automatically be rewarded in 5 days to you.  thanks!